# How can I refresh partial view and the main view at the same time?

Tags: c#, jquery, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

1) Here is the controller method of my main view:

```
public ActionResult PredefPageLoad()
    {
        List<PredefineViewsView> predefViewsViews = null;
        try
        {
            using (PanSenseEntities context = new PanSenseEntities())
            {
                int userID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["LoggedUserID"]);
                predefViewsViews = (from x in context.PredefineViewsViews where x.UserID == userID select x).ToList();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
        return View(predefViewsViews);
    }
```

2) So my main view is displays a web grid which contains in each row an ID, a name and an **amount of it's sub names**, as well as image icons for add, edit **and an icon that opens a partial view that displays the name and all of its sub names**:

```
 @{
        var grid = new WebGrid(Model);
  }
    <div id="gridContent">

    <button type="button" id="createNewPredefinedView" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">@Html.Localize("createNew")</button>

        @grid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
    headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
    footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
    alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
    selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
    rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
    mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
    columns:

        grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("PredefID", format: @<text>  <span class="display-mode" id="PredefViewID">@item.PredefineViewID </span> <label id="PredefID" class="edit-mode">@item.PredefineViewID</label> </text>, style: "col1Width"),


            grid.Column("", format: @<text>
            <img class="edit-table display-mode click_images" src="~/Images/edit.png" />
            <img class="delete-table display-mode click_images" src="~/Images/delete.png" />
            <img class="open-sensors display-mode click_images" src="~/Images/Sensor.png" />
            <img class="save-table edit-mode click_images" src="~/Images/save.png" />
            <img class="cancel-table edit-mode click_images" src="~/Images/cancel.png" />
            </text>, style: "col2Width", canSort: false),

            grid.Column("PredefName", @Html.Localize("name").ToString(), format: @<text>  <span class="display-mode">  <label id="lblPredefName">@item.Name</label> </span> <input type="text" id="PredefName" value="@item.Name" class="edit-mode" /> </text>, style: "col1Width", canSort: false),

            grid.Column("AmountOfSensors", @Html.Localize("amountOfSensors").ToString(), format: @<text>  <span class="display-mode" id="lblAmountOfSensors">  @item.SensorNo </span> <label id="AmountOfSensors" class="edit-mode"> @item.SensorNo </label> </text>, style: "col2Width", canSort: false)
         ))
    </div>



    <div id="sensorNames">

    </div>
```

3) I gave this image icon "class:open-sensors" that when I click opens the mentioned partial view nested inside the div "sensorNames", and here is the java script for that action:

```
$('.open-sensors').on('click', function () {
        var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
        var PredefID = tr.find("#PredefID").html();
        var divSensorNames = $("#sensorNames");
        var urlShowSensors = "@Url.Action("ShowSensorNames", "PredefinedViews", new { predefinedViewID = "PredefID" })";
        urlShowSensors = urlShowSensors.replace("PredefID", PredefID);
        $(divSensorNames).load(urlShowSensors);
        });
```

4) The controller method then filters the selected ID:

```
public ActionResult ShowSensorNames(string predefinedViewID)
    {
        List<PredefineViewItemsView> predefViewItemsViews = null;
        try
        {
            using (PanSenseEntities context = new PanSenseEntities())
            {
                int predefViewID = Convert.ToInt32(predefinedViewID);
                predefViewItemsViews = (from x in context.PredefineViewItemsViews where x.PredefineViewID == predefViewID select x).ToList();
            }
        }
        return PartialView("DisplaySensors", predefViewItemsViews);
    }
```

5) And it opens the partial view inside the "sensorNames" div:

```
 @{
    var gridSensors = new WebGrid(Model, canPage:false);
}
@gridSensors.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
    headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
    footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
    alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
    selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
    rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
    mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
    columns:


    gridSensors.Columns(
            gridSensors.Column("PredefineViewID", format: @<text>  <span id="PredefineViewID">@item.PredefineViewID </span>  </text>, style: "col1Width"),

            gridSensors.Column("PredefineViewsItemID", format: @<text>  <span id="PredefineViewsItemID">@item.PredefineViewsItemID </span>  </text>, style: "col1Width"),

            gridSensors.Column("", format: @<text><img class="sensor-delete-table click_images" alt="@Html.Localize("delete")" title="@Html.Localize("delete")" src="~/Images/delete.png" /></text>, style: "col1Width", canSort: false),

            gridSensors.Column("PredefName", @Html.Localize("name").ToString(), format: @<text>  <span><label id="lblPredefineViewName">@item.PredefineViewName</label> </span>  </text>, style: "col1Width", canSort: false),

            gridSensors.Column("PredefName", @Html.Localize("sensorName").ToString(), format: @<text>  <span><label id="lblSensorName">@item.SensorName</label> </span>  </text>, style: "col3Width", canSort: false)

    ))
```

**Here is the question part- how do I delete my sub name (inside the partial view of course) using the image icon in the third column "class=sensor-delete-table" AND refresh this web-grid (take out the deleted row) as well as the main view web-grid (decrement the number of amount of sub names by 1)?**

6) **What I managed to do** *was delete the record in my database and only refresh the partial view, but not the main view*:

```
$(function () {
        $(".sensor-delete-table").on("click", function () {
            var divSensorNames = $("#sensorNames");
            var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
            var PredefineViewsItemID = tr.find("#PredefineViewsItemID").html();
            var PredefineViewID = tr.find("#PredefineViewID").html();
            var flag = confirm('@Html.Localize("deleteCheck")');
            var urlShowNewSensors = "@Url.Action("ShowSensorNames", "PredefinedViews", new { predefinedViewID = "PredefineViewID" })";
            urlShowNewSensors = urlShowNewSensors.replace("PredefineViewID", PredefineViewID);
            if (PredefineViewID != "" && flag) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: '@Url.Action("DeleteSensor", "PredefinedViews")',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ pviID: PredefineViewsItemID, pID: PredefineViewID}),
                    dataType: "json",
                    complete: function (result) {
                    $("#sensorNames").html(result.responseText);
                    },
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

7) This is the delete method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DeleteSensor(int pviID, int pID)
    {
        using (PanSenseEntities context = new PanSenseEntities())
        {
            tblPredefineViewItem existing = context.tblPredefineViewItems.Find(pviID);
            if (existing != null)
            {
                context.tblPredefineViewItems.Remove(existing);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("ShowSensorNames", "PredefinedViews", new { predefinedViewID = pID });
    }
```

This successfully deletes the sub name and takes it to the method which i mentioned in step 4) from where it goes into the "complete:" from step 6).
You may ask why didnt I use "success:" instead of complete? Beacause it doens't register that it did  anything, and neither does "finish:" or "done:".
What I attempted as well was to do a "window.location.reload()" and tried putting it before the "$("#sensorNames").html(result.responseText);" line and every other place I could think of, but it always ends up in the wrong order that I want it to. First I want it to refresh the page and then open the new webgrid with one less sub name, but it just does the opposite- it removes the deleted one and it refreshes the page, so I am left with a refreshed main view without an open partial view- unless I open it manually but thats not what I want.

Sorry for the long post, this is my first time asking a question here.

**8)Edit to show resulting html, the first table is:**

```
<div id="gridContent" class="table-responsive col-md-6" style="padding-top: 20px; ">

<button type="button" id="createNewPredefinedView" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">Create new</button>

<table class="webgrid-table">
    <thead>
        <tr class="webgrid-header">
            <th scope="col" style="display: none;">
                <a href="/PredefinedViews/PredefPageLoad?sort=PredefID&amp;sortdir=ASC">PredefID</a>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                Name
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                Amount of Sensors
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="webgrid-row-style">
            <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span class="display-mode" id="PredefViewID">18 </span> <label id="PredefID" class="edit-mode" style="display: none;">18</label> </td>
            <td class="col2Width">


                <img class="edit-table display-mode click_images" alt="Edit" title="Edit" src="/Images/edit.png">
                <img class="delete-table display-mode click_images" alt="Delete" title="Delete" src="/Images/delete.png">

                <img class="open-sensors display-mode click_images" alt="View of Existing Sensors" title="View of Existing Sensors" src="/Images/Sensor.png">



                <img class="save-table edit-mode click_images" alt="Save" title="Save" src="/Images/save.png" style="display: none;">
                <img class="cancel-table edit-mode click_images" alt="Cancel" title="Cancel" src="/Images/cancel.png" style="display: none;">

            </td>
            <td class="col1Width">  <span class="display-mode">  <label id="lblPredefName">pokusaj4555</label> </span> <input type="text" id="PredefName" value="pokusaj4555" class="edit-mode" style="display: none;"> </td>
            <td class="col2Width">  <span class="display-mode" id="lblAmountOfSensors">  10 </span> <label id="AmountOfSensors" class="edit-mode" style="display: none;"> 10 </label> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="webgrid-alternating-row">
            <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span class="display-mode" id="PredefViewID">19 </span> <label id="PredefID" class="edit-mode" style="display: none;">19</label> </td>
            <td class="col2Width">


                <img class="edit-table display-mode click_images" alt="Edit" title="Edit" src="/Images/edit.png">
                <img class="delete-table display-mode click_images" alt="Delete" title="Delete" src="/Images/delete.png">

                <img class="open-sensors display-mode click_images" alt="View of Existing Sensors" title="View of Existing Sensors" src="/Images/Sensor.png">



                <img class="save-table edit-mode click_images" alt="Save" title="Save" src="/Images/save.png" style="display: none;">
                <img class="cancel-table edit-mode click_images" alt="Cancel" title="Cancel" src="/Images/cancel.png" style="display: none;">

            </td>
            <td class="col1Width">  <span class="display-mode">  <label id="lblPredefName">pokusaj1333</label> </span> <input type="text" id="PredefName" value="pokusaj1333" class="edit-mode" style="display: none;"> </td>
            <td class="col2Width">  <span class="display-mode" id="lblAmountOfSensors">  11 </span> <label id="AmountOfSensors" class="edit-mode" style="display: none;"> 11 </label> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="webgrid-row-style">
            <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span class="display-mode" id="PredefViewID">20 </span> <label id="PredefID" class="edit-mode" style="display: none;">20</label> </td>
            <td class="col2Width">


                <img class="edit-table display-mode click_images" alt="Edit" title="Edit" src="/Images/edit.png">
                <img class="delete-table display-mode click_images" alt="Delete" title="Delete" src="/Images/delete.png">

                <img class="open-sensors display-mode click_images" alt="View of Existing Sensors" title="View of Existing Sensors" src="/Images/Sensor.png">



                <img class="save-table edit-mode click_images" alt="Save" title="Save" src="/Images/save.png" style="display: none;">
                <img class="cancel-table edit-mode click_images" alt="Cancel" title="Cancel" src="/Images/cancel.png" style="display: none;">

            </td>
            <td class="col1Width">  <span class="display-mode">  <label id="lblPredefName">pokusaj3</label> </span> <input type="text" id="PredefName" value="pokusaj3" class="edit-mode" style="display: none;"> </td>
            <td class="col2Width">  <span class="display-mode" id="lblAmountOfSensors">  10 </span> <label id="AmountOfSensors" class="edit-mode" style="display: none;"> 10 </label> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="webgrid-alternating-row">
            <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span class="display-mode" id="PredefViewID">21 </span> <label id="PredefID" class="edit-mode" style="display: none;">21</label> </td>
            <td class="col2Width">


                <img class="edit-table display-mode click_images" alt="Edit" title="Edit" src="/Images/edit.png">
                <img class="delete-table display-mode click_images" alt="Delete" title="Delete" src="/Images/delete.png">

                <img class="open-sensors display-mode click_images" alt="View of Existing Sensors" title="View of Existing Sensors" src="/Images/Sensor.png">



                <img class="save-table edit-mode click_images" alt="Save" title="Save" src="/Images/save.png" style="display: none;">
                <img class="cancel-table edit-mode click_images" alt="Cancel" title="Cancel" src="/Images/cancel.png" style="display: none;">

            </td>
            <td class="col1Width">  <span class="display-mode">  <label id="lblPredefName">asdasd</label> </span> <input type="text" id="PredefName" value="asdasd" class="edit-mode" style="display: none;"> </td>
            <td class="col2Width">  <span class="display-mode" id="lblAmountOfSensors">  3 </span> <label id="AmountOfSensors" class="edit-mode" style="display: none;"> 3 </label> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="webgrid-row-style">
            <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span class="display-mode" id="PredefViewID">22 </span> <label id="PredefID" class="edit-mode" style="display: none;">22</label> </td>
            <td class="col2Width">


                <img class="edit-table display-mode click_images" alt="Edit" title="Edit" src="/Images/edit.png">
                <img class="delete-table display-mode click_images" alt="Delete" title="Delete" src="/Images/delete.png">

                <img class="open-sensors display-mode click_images" alt="View of Existing Sensors" title="View of Existing Sensors" src="/Images/Sensor.png">



                <img class="save-table edit-mode click_images" alt="Save" title="Save" src="/Images/save.png" style="display: none;">
                <img class="cancel-table edit-mode click_images" alt="Cancel" title="Cancel" src="/Images/cancel.png" style="display: none;">

            </td>
            <td class="col1Width">  <span class="display-mode">  <label id="lblPredefName">qwer</label> </span> <input type="text" id="PredefName" value="qwer" class="edit-mode" style="display: none;"> </td>
            <td class="col2Width">  <span class="display-mode" id="lblAmountOfSensors">  3 </span> <label id="AmountOfSensors" class="edit-mode" style="display: none;"> 3 </label> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="webgrid-alternating-row">
            <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span class="display-mode" id="PredefViewID">23 </span> <label id="PredefID" class="edit-mode" style="display: none;">23</label> </td>
            <td class="col2Width">


                <img class="edit-table display-mode click_images" alt="Edit" title="Edit" src="/Images/edit.png">
                <img class="delete-table display-mode click_images" alt="Delete" title="Delete" src="/Images/delete.png">

                <img class="open-sensors display-mode click_images" alt="View of Existing Sensors" title="View of Existing Sensors" src="/Images/Sensor.png">



                <img class="save-table edit-mode click_images" alt="Save" title="Save" src="/Images/save.png" style="display: none;">
                <img class="cancel-table edit-mode click_images" alt="Cancel" title="Cancel" src="/Images/cancel.png" style="display: none;">

            </td>
            <td class="col1Width">  <span class="display-mode">  <label id="lblPredefName">asd123</label> </span> <input type="text" id="PredefName" value="asd123" class="edit-mode" style="display: none;"> </td>
            <td class="col2Width">  <span class="display-mode" id="lblAmountOfSensors">  4 </span> <label id="AmountOfSensors" class="edit-mode" style="display: none;"> 4 </label> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="webgrid-row-style">
            <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span class="display-mode" id="PredefViewID">1052 </span> <label id="PredefID" class="edit-mode" style="display: none;">1052</label> </td>
            <td class="col2Width">


                <img class="edit-table display-mode click_images" alt="Edit" title="Edit" src="/Images/edit.png">
                <img class="delete-table display-mode click_images" alt="Delete" title="Delete" src="/Images/delete.png">

                <img class="open-sensors display-mode click_images" alt="View of Existing Sensors" title="View of Existing Sensors" src="/Images/Sensor.png">



                <img class="save-table edit-mode click_images" alt="Save" title="Save" src="/Images/save.png" style="display: none;">
                <img class="cancel-table edit-mode click_images" alt="Cancel" title="Cancel" src="/Images/cancel.png" style="display: none;">

            </td>
            <td class="col1Width">  <span class="display-mode">  <label id="lblPredefName">qwerty</label> </span> <input type="text" id="PredefName" value="qwerty" class="edit-mode" style="display: none;"> </td>
            <td class="col2Width">  <span class="display-mode" id="lblAmountOfSensors">  0 </span> <label id="AmountOfSensors" class="edit-mode" style="display: none;"> 0 </label> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="webgrid-alternating-row">
            <td class="col1Width" style="display: none;">  <span class="display-mode" id="PredefViewID">2052 </span> <label id="PredefID" class="edit-mode" style="display: none;">2052</label> </td>
            <td class="col2Width">


                <img class="edit-table display-mode click_images" alt="Edit" title="Edit" src="/Images/edit.png">
                <img class="delete-table display-mode click_images" alt="Delete" title="Delete" src="/Images/delete.png">

                <img class="open-sensors display-mode click_images" alt="View of Existing Sensors" title="View of Existing Sensors" src="/Images/Sensor.png">



                <img class="save-table edit-mode click_images" alt="Save" title="Save" src="/Images/save.png" style="display: none;">
                <img class="cancel-table edit-mode click_images" alt="Cancel" title="Cancel" src="/Images/cancel.png" style="display: none;">

            </td>
            <td class="col1Width">  <span class="display-mode">  <label id="lblPredefName">qwerty</label> </span> <input type="text" id="PredefName" value="qwerty" class="edit-mode" style="display: none;"> </td>
            <td class="col2Width">  <span class="display-mode" id="lblAmountOfSensors">  0 </span> <label id="AmountOfSensors" class="edit-mode" style="display: none;"> 0 </label> </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Here is the second table:**

```
<table class="webgrid-table">
    <thead>
        <tr class="webgrid-header">
            <th scope="col">
                <a href="/PredefinedViews/ShowSensorNames?predefinedViewID=20&amp;sort=PredefineViewID&amp;sortdir=ASC">PredefineViewID</a>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <a href="/PredefinedViews/ShowSensorNames?predefinedViewID=20&amp;sort=PredefineViewsItemID&amp;sortdir=ASC">PredefineViewsItemID</a>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                Name
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                Sensor Name
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="webgrid-row-style">
            <td class="col1Width">  <span id="PredefineViewID">20 </span>  </td>
            <td class="col1Width">  <span id="PredefineViewsItemID">42 </span>  </td>
            <td class="col1Width"><img class="sensor-delete-table click_images" alt="Delete" title="Delete" src="/Images/delete.png"></td>
            <td class="col1Width">  <span><label id="lblPredefineViewName">pokusaj3</label> </span>  </td>
            <td class="col3Width">  <span><label id="lblSensorName">Solar radiation </label> </span>  </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="webgrid-alternating-row">
            <td class="col1Width">  <span id="PredefineViewID">20 </span>  </td>
            <td class="col1Width">  <span id="PredefineViewsItemID">1123 </span>  </td>
            <td class="col1Width"><img class="sensor-delete-table click_images" alt="Delete" title="Delete" src="/Images/delete.png"></td>
            <td class="col1Width">  <span><label id="lblPredefineViewName">pokusaj3</label> </span>  </td>
            <td class="col3Width">  <span><label id="lblSensorName">Soil Temperature </label> </span>  </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="webgrid-row-style">
            <td class="col1Width">  <span id="PredefineViewID">20 </span>  </td>
            <td class="col1Width">  <span id="PredefineViewsItemID">1124 </span>  </td>
            <td class="col1Width"><img class="sensor-delete-table click_images" alt="Delete" title="Delete" src="/Images/delete.png"></td>
            <td class="col1Width">  <span><label id="lblPredefineViewName">pokusaj3</label> </span>  </td>
            <td class="col3Width">  <span><label id="lblSensorName">Soil Moisture na 15cm</label> </span>  </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="webgrid-alternating-row">
            <td class="col1Width">  <span id="PredefineViewID">20 </span>  </td>
            <td class="col1Width">  <span id="PredefineViewsItemID">1125 </span>  </td>
            <td class="col1Width"><img class="sensor-delete-table click_images" alt="Delete" title="Delete" src="/Images/delete.png"></td>
            <td class="col1Width">  <span><label id="lblPredefineViewName">pokusaj3</label> </span>  </td>
            <td class="col3Width">  <span><label id="lblSensorName">Soil Moisture na 30cm</label> </span>  </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="webgrid-row-style">
            <td class="col1Width">  <span id="PredefineViewID">20 </span>  </td>
            <td class="col1Width">  <span id="PredefineViewsItemID">1126 </span>  </td>
            <td class="col1Width"><img class="sensor-delete-table click_images" alt="Delete" title="Delete" src="/Images/delete.png"></td>
            <td class="col1Width">  <span><label id="lblPredefineViewName">pokusaj3</label> </span>  </td>
            <td class="col3Width">  <span><label id="lblSensorName">Leaf wetness prvi</label> </span>  </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="webgrid-alternating-row">
            <td class="col1Width">  <span id="PredefineViewID">20 </span>  </td>
            <td class="col1Width">  <span id="PredefineViewsItemID">1127 </span>  </td>
            <td class="col1Width"><img class="sensor-delete-table click_images" alt="Delete" title="Delete" src="/Images/delete.png"></td>
            <td class="col1Width">  <span><label id="lblPredefineViewName">pokusaj3</label> </span>  </td>
            <td class="col3Width">  <span><label id="lblSensorName">Ait temperature </label> </span>  </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="webgrid-row-style">
            <td class="col1Width">  <span id="PredefineViewID">20 </span>  </td>
            <td class="col1Width">  <span id="PredefineViewsItemID">1128 </span>  </td>
            <td class="col1Width"><img class="sensor-delete-table click_images" alt="Delete" title="Delete" src="/Images/delete.png"></td>
            <td class="col1Width">  <span><label id="lblPredefineViewName">pokusaj3</label> </span>  </td>
            <td class="col3Width">  <span><label id="lblSensorName">Air humidity </label> </span>  </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="webgrid-alternating-row">
            <td class="col1Width">  <span id="PredefineViewID">20 </span>  </td>
            <td class="col1Width">  <span id="PredefineViewsItemID">1129 </span>  </td>
            <td class="col1Width"><img class="sensor-delete-table click_images" alt="Delete" title="Delete" src="/Images/delete.png"></td>
            <td class="col1Width">  <span><label id="lblPredefineViewName">pokusaj3</label> </span>  </td>
            <td class="col3Width">  <span><label id="lblSensorName">Wind speed </label> </span>  </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="webgrid-row-style">
            <td class="col1Width">  <span id="PredefineViewID">20 </span>  </td>
            <td class="col1Width">  <span id="PredefineViewsItemID">1130 </span>  </td>
            <td class="col1Width"><img class="sensor-delete-table click_images" alt="Delete" title="Delete" src="/Images/delete.png"></td>
            <td class="col1Width">  <span><label id="lblPredefineViewName">pokusaj3</label> </span>  </td>
            <td class="col3Width">  <span><label id="lblSensorName">Wind direction </label> </span>  </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="webgrid-alternating-row">
            <td class="col1Width">  <span id="PredefineViewID">20 </span>  </td>
            <td class="col1Width">  <span id="PredefineViewsItemID">1131 </span>  </td>
            <td class="col1Width"><img class="sensor-delete-table click_images" alt="Delete" title="Delete" src="/Images/delete.png"></td>
            <td class="col1Width">  <span><label id="lblPredefineViewName">pokusaj3</label> </span>  </td>
            <td class="col3Width">  <span><label id="lblSensorName">Precipitation </label> </span>  </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply remove the row from the webgrid manually in jquery ? You already have the row in the tr var.

```
var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');

complete: function (result) {
    tr.remove(); //this will remove the row from the table.    
},
```

**UPDATE :**

When you get use to manipulating the DOM with jquery. You ended with making ajax call that return json and update the html dynamically with the json return. There a lot of javascript framework that you can use but you can achieve everything with jquery to.

That said, if you don't want to learn how to manipulate the DOM to deal with your current situation, i will do this. I hope you are using ViewModel to display the view. So in your main page model let's name it MainPageViewModel. Add a property call IDPartialViewDeleted. When you delete the row. Update that property in the MainPageViewModel. RedirectToAction that reload the entire page (probably index). Check if the IDPartialViewDeleted has a value, if so call your function that display the partial view with the specific ID. That will do the trick.

As i said, if you want to manipulate the DOM. All you have to do is.
Remove the row from the partialview.

```
tr.remove();
```

And find the control in the main grid that contain the number of children and update that value. Something like this.

```
var count = tr.closest("MainTableIdorClass").find("MyControlWithNumberOfChildren").val();
count--;
tr.closest("MainTableIdorClass").find("MyControlWithNumberOfChildren").val(count);
```

This way you don't even have to return something from the server and everything is fresh on the client. I hope it's clear.

**UPDATE**
An other edit. To make it simple let's introduce a new and very usefull concept : custom attribute.
Do this on the generation of the table one.

```
grid.Column("AmountOfSensors", @Html.Localize("amountOfSensors").ToString(), format: @<text>  <span class="display-mode" data-id="@item.PredefineViewID" id="lblAmountOfSensors">  @item.SensorNo </span> <label id="AmountOfSensors" class="edit-mode"> @item.SensorNo </label> </text>, style: "col2Width", canSort: false)
```

Add the id to you span.
Then update it on the delete this way :

```
$("[data-id='" + PredefineViewID " +']").text(parseInt($("[data-id='" + PredefineViewID " +']").text()) - 1);
```

Easy isn't it ?

**UPDATE**
Try this :

```
$(".sensor-delete-table").on("click", function () {
            var divSensorNames = $("#sensorNames");
            var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
            var PredefineViewsItemID = tr.find("#PredefineViewsItemID").html();
            var PredefineViewID = tr.find("#PredefineViewID").html();
            var flag = confirm('@Html.Localize("deleteCheck")');
            var urlShowNewSensors = "@Url.Action("ShowSensorNames", "PredefinedViews", new { predefinedViewID = "PredefineViewID" })";
            urlShowNewSensors = urlShowNewSensors.replace("PredefineViewID", PredefineViewID);
            if (PredefineViewID != "" && flag) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: '@Url.Action("DeleteSensor", "PredefinedViews")',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ pviID: PredefineViewsItemID, pID: PredefineViewID}),
                    dataType: "json",
                    complete: function (result) {
                    $("#sensorNames").html(result.responseText);
                    var amount = parseInt($("[data-id='" + PredefineViewID + "']").text());
                    amount--;
                  $("[data-id='" + PredefineViewID + "']").text(amount.toString());
                    },
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: I had a space in the string, thats why i had a NaN result, now it works perfectly, thank you very much for your time!