# How do I load a view and then a partial view within it in a MVC project using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Whatever I do, I keep getting the reverse order. I just want to refresh the entire page after ajax finishes a certain action and then simply load a certain partial view, this is my attempt:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: '@Url.Action("DeleteSensor", "PredefinedViews")',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ pviID: PredefineViewsItemID, pID: PredefineViewID }),
                    dataType: "json",
                    complete: function (result) {
                        location.reload(true);
                    },
                    success: function (result) {;
                        var urlShowSensors = "@Url.Action("ShowSensorNames", "PredefinedViews", new { predefinedViewID = "PredefID" })";
                        urlShowSensors = urlShowSensors.replace("PredefID", PredefineViewID);
                        $(divSensorNames).load(urlShowSensors);
```

In the debug I see that it successfully loads the partial view, **but then it ends up doing the location.reload(true); LASTLY** which in turn leaves me with an open view without an open partial view. **Is there a way I can FIRST make it do location.reload(true); and THEN load my partial view?**

**UPDATE!**
It appears I never put a document.ready in my script tags, here is my entire script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".sensor-delete-table").on("click", function () {
            var divSensorNames = $("#sensorNames");
            var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
            var PredefineViewsItemID = tr.find("#PredefineViewsItemID").html();
            var PredefineViewID = tr.find("#PredefineViewID").html();
            var amount = parseInt($("[data-id='" + PredefineViewID + "']").text());
            var flag = confirm('@Html.Localize("deleteCheck")');
            var urlShowNewSensors = "@Url.Action("ShowSensorNames", "PredefinedViews", new { predefinedViewID = "PredefineViewID" })";
            urlShowNewSensors = urlShowNewSensors.replace("PredefineViewID", PredefineViewID);
            if (PredefineViewID != "" && flag) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: '@Url.Action("DeleteSensor", "PredefinedViews")',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ pviID: PredefineViewsItemID, pID: PredefineViewID }),
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (result) {
                        location.reload(true);
                    },
                    complete: function (result) {

                        var urlShowSensors = "@Url.Action("ShowSensorNames", "PredefinedViews", new { predefinedViewID = "PredefID" })";
                        urlShowSensors = urlShowSensors.replace("PredefID", PredefineViewID);
                        $(divSensorNames).load(urlShowSensors);
                    },

                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I thought I could do it like that, so can anyone correct my code here? Basically when i click a button, it deletes a row in a table in my partial view and it goes to a controller where it deletes the record from the data base. Now if everything went accordingly I want to refresh a table in my main view which is why I insist on doing a location.reload and then I want to load my partial view, which is why i need an url to be loaded on a certain div.

Answer (score 1):

Load the partial view in document.ready function

and put the location.reload() in success block

```
       $(document).ready(function()
       {
           var urlShowSensors = "@Url.Action("ShowSensorNames", "PredefinedViews",
                        new {                 predefinedViewID = "PredefID" })";
                    urlShowSensors = urlShowSensors.replace("PredefID",  
                                                PredefineViewID);
                    $(divSensorNames).load(urlShowSensors);
       });


       $(".sensor-delete-table").on("click", function () {
       $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: '@Url.Action("DeleteSensor", "PredefinedViews")',
                data: JSON.stringify({ pviID: PredefineViewsItemID, pID: PredefineViewID
                    }   ),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                             location.reload(true);}});
       });
```

Comment: And where should i put the document.ready function? after the ajax call?

Comment: No .. document.ready() should be at the top of javascript function which is executed on each page load. After completing your ajax call, ie your success function, you do a location.reload(). so entire page will be getting refreshed. on loading the page it executes document.ready() which in turn loads your partialview.

Comment: It seems you don't understand the page life cycle. `document.ready` is called only ones in a page life cycle. http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/introducing-document-ready/

Comment: @Amila Since on calling loaction.reload() means page is loading as new page . so it executes as fresh page is loading. sop document.ready() gets executed

Comment: @HamidNarikkoden My above comment is for him asking where to put it and as it seems he's trying to use jQuery ajax without the knowledge of the piece of code that is important to jQuery.

Comment: Okay so firstly the location.reload(true) works ONLY if it is in a complete block. Secondly, when i put the document ready above the `$(".sensor-delete-table").on("click", function ()` code it doesnt do any thing

Comment: how does the document ready and the `$(divSensorNames).load(urlShowSensors);` within it know when i clicked `".sensor-delete-table"` ?

Comment: Above comment suggest that you have very little knowledge on `jQuery`. I'm really going to suggest you study `jQuery` first. There are plenty of good tutorials all over the internet.

Comment: Im asking it because the code provided above does not work for me, I may have missed the whole point document ready, but all my java script has worked untill this point, so Im asking for a working code in order to understand it and implement it in the future, otherwise I feel (and have results that back it up) that i kind of have a grasp how javascript works and I really did have success with it these past few weeks.

Comment: @Hamid Narikkoden thats the thing I dont want the partial view to load on each page load, just in this particular case when I press the image class '".sensor-delete-table"'

Answer (score 0):

it is doing exactly what you have coded.

`complete` and `success` callbacks that you have overridden gets called on your call to `@Url.Action("DeleteSensor", "PredefinedViews")`. so you are left out with a view as if the user has gone to the page for the first time. There's no point of loading the partial view in the `success callback` as the whole page got reloaded in the `complete callback`.

As far as I can understand by looking at your code, you should call whatever in the `success` callback within the `document ready`.

```
$(function(){
    var urlShowSensors = "@Url.Action("ShowSensorNames", "PredefinedViews", new { predefinedViewID = "PredefID" })";
    urlShowSensors = urlShowSensors.replace("PredefID", PredefineViewID);
    $(divSensorNames).load(urlShowSensors);
});
```

Not sure what conditions you have to check. but it doesn't seem that you are using the response from the ajax call within the `success callback`. so the above should work.

**UPDATE**
To answer your update

As you are already using partial views and as it seem you understand the concept of it, why don't you move the table to a partial view as well and call it just like you are trying to load `ShowSensorNames` partial and comment out the `location.reload(true);` code.

First create a partial view (e.g call it MyTable.cshtml) and move your table html to it and strongly type it with the Model.

now in your View where the Table used to be. Do the following

```
<div id="myTableContainer">
    @Html.Partial("MyTable", Model)
</div>
```

Now create a action in your controller called `MyTable` which returns a partial view

```
public ActionResult MyTable()
{    
    var myTableDataModel = //retrieve table data

    return PartialView(myTableDataModel);
}
```

Now lets get to the javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(".sensor-delete-table").on("click", function () {
        var divSensorNames = $("#sensorNames");
        var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
        var PredefineViewsItemID = tr.find("#PredefineViewsItemID").html();
        var PredefineViewID = tr.find("#PredefineViewID").html();
        var amount = parseInt($("[data-id='" + PredefineViewID + "']").text());
        var flag = confirm('@Html.Localize("deleteCheck")');
        var urlShowNewSensors = "@Url.Action("ShowSensorNames", "PredefinedViews", new { predefinedViewID = "PredefineViewID" })";
        urlShowNewSensors = urlShowNewSensors.replace("PredefineViewID", PredefineViewID);
        if (PredefineViewID != "" && flag) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: '@Url.Action("DeleteSensor", "PredefinedViews")',
                data: JSON.stringify({ pviID: PredefineViewsItemID, pID: PredefineViewID }),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    ///location.reload(true);
                },
                complete: function (result) {

                    var urlShowSensors = '@Url.Action("ShowSensorNames", "PredefinedViews", new { predefinedViewID = "PredefID" })';
                    var urlMyTable = '@Url.Action("MyTable", "PredefinedViews")';
                    urlShowSensors = urlShowSensors.replace("PredefID", PredefineViewID);
                    $(divSensorNames).load(urlShowSensors);
                    $("#myTableContainer").load(urlMyTable);
                },

            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: The first table is the only thing displayed in my main view. The second table in my partial view is influenced by a button click in my fisrt table. I posted a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27170822/how-can-i-refresh-partial-view-and-the-main-view-at-the-same-time/27171081#27171081 but ended up accepting the answer because I thought javascript could take care of my problem failing to realise that I never check if the database is updated. But now I really need to reload the man view and THEN the partial view