# How to refresh mvc views and partial views simultaneously using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a button click that deletes a row in a table of a partial view, I want that click to also refresh the entire parent page **AND** once refreshed to reopen the partial view which will now have one less row. **Here is the tricky bit, I never need to load the partial view if the entire parent page is opened normally (via action link or what ever)** Any suggestions?

Comment: My first suggestion would be to stop using partial views etc. and start using a client side data binding library such as Knockout, Angular etc.. because you are causing complexities which don't need to be there

Comment: @No1_Melman can client side data binding libraries you mentioned be used in MVC-5?

Comment: Absolutely, because it is javascript it is agnostic of what server side programming language you choose. With MVC you can add `<script></script>` tags into pages, you can also bundle up the files just like it does with jQuery, so this means that you can even have file version with source control!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ajax (jquery ajax is the most easiest to understand i think).so when parent page had loaded just bind event to your button and use ajax to url.action

```
 $(document).on('click', '.appoint', load);

     function load(userId, type) {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("AppointUser", "Profile")',
                traditional: true,
                data: {
                    userId: userId,
                    type: type
                },
                success: function(response) {"smth"}
                  });
        }
```

Comment: I tried that and I get the opposite result, FIRST it loads the partial view and THEN it does the entire page reload.

Comment: So where would I in this example put the `location.reload(true);`, and then where would I put `$(someDiv).load(SomeUrlAction);` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use datatables .. The best library for making the tables in Jquery. You can give it data in any form using ajax request . It also has many functions that will solve your problem of dynamically re-rendering the grid ..

Have a look at http://www.datatables.net/

Comment: I already have my project build around web-grids, is that a huge factor?

Comment: That actually depends on how scalable and loosely coupled your application is .. I Would suggest to first try modelling your DOM such that you can use the AJAX to reload it ...Hence first give try to that ...

Comment: his issue is refreshing the enclosing page, not just the data table/grid, which he is refreshing fine. Datatables will not solve that.

Answer (score 0):

Just Hide the partial view on Page load in java Script

By Hide the Div that you used to load the partialView

```
      or
```

Load the partial view as below

```
@Html.Partial("PartialViewName", new Classname())
```

**ClassName i defined in above is must match with your partial view nameSpace**

Answer (score 0):

post your code to get more useful feedback, but the gist of it is this, you want to be able to load your partial conditionally upon load. The code to delete the row, and reload the parent page, should pass a flag (query parameter) to the enclosing page to let it know this is a special case (e.g. reloadPartial=true)

You then pass that flag back in your ViewModel to your parent view, which will use it to enable the conditional load of the partial.

Again, will be much easier to explain with your code posted.

Comment: I was reluctant to do so because this is my third time asking the same question. Here is [the first time I asked it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27170822/how-can-i-refresh-partial-view-and-the-main-view-at-the-same-time/27171081#27171081)
and here is the [second time, just 2 hours ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27378610/how-do-i-load-a-view-and-then-a-partial-view-within-it-in-a-mvc-project-using-ja/27378753#27378753) which is more to the point

Comment: ok, you are missing the life cycle of the page. Basically your AJAX complete callback will be triggered regardless, and once you reload the location, you are getting a new page, and nothing up till then matters. So you really should forget about reloading the partial view. Just reload the page on success but pass it a query parameter to indicate you want to reload the partial view. It is really not that hard, but you need a good grasp on the sequence of events to do it, and i think you are better off understanding that first.

Comment: "pass it a query parameter to indicate you want to reload the partial view" <---How? Do I just add something to the `location.reload(true)`? :D

Comment: I have already figured out how to reload the partial view only, but as soon as i try to reload the entire page, it will always be the last thing it does regardless of what i do.

Comment: right, because reloading the whole page, gives you a new page, everything that happened till then is gone. It is the same as if you load facebook.com instead of your page, nothing that you did in javascript up till that point matters. it is all gone.

Comment: do not use location.reload(). Instead do something like location.href=location.href?reloadPartial=true;  but keep in mind if you delete multiple rows your query string will double up, so you will want to do some simple test, to see if the current page was loaded with reloadPartial=true already, at which case you just say: location.reload(true) or location.href=location.href;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66489/discussion-between-vrankela-and-born2code).